# Odoo create an automatic report and send it to specific user using email template

Tags: python, xml, jinja2, odoo-10, odoo-9

I would like to generate an automatic report and on the first of every month send it to specific email using email template.

I am thinking to use:

- ir.cron object for automatically calling method on the first of every
  month
- stock.location object with get_data() method for getting data
- mail.template object for sending data for specific user by email.

I wrote **get_data()** method to get **power_difference** values from all the locations. The problem is when I am calling **send_mail()** method. I get my self.id variable equal to False so as I understand mail template can't be rendered.

What am I doing wrong? I am getting everything I need from get_data() method but the problem is how to pass **records** value to mail template and send the email.

get_data() method:

```
@api.model
def get_data(self):
    locations = self.env['stock.location'].search([('id','child_of',[361]),('usage','=','view')]
    records=[]
    location_power_changes={}
       for location in locations:
        power = location.power
    location.power_difference = location.last_month_power - power
    location.last_month_power = power
    location_changes['power_difference'] = location.power_difference
        records.append(location_power_changes)
    template = self.env.ref('t_stock.email_template_1')
    self.env['mail.template'].browse(template.id).send_mail(self.id)
```

mail template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <record id="email_template_t" model="mail.template">
            <field name="name">T</field>
            <field name="email_from">example@mail.com</field>
            <field name="email_to">example1@mail.com</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="t_stock.model_stock_location"/>
            <field name="body_html"><![CDATA[
                <p>Test</p>
                <table>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <th>T1</th>

                </tr>
                % if object.get_data():
                    % for values in object.get_data()
                    <tr>
                            <td>${values['power_difference']}</td>
                   </tr>
                   % endfor
                   % endif
                   </tbody></table><br>
        ]]></field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: This looks some lot of work to do....If you got the answer, pls post here@fueggit